# a question about this strncpy function in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, server, client, strncpy

im currently working on portscanner for my network scanner app with socket in c .
i found this code , and i want to understand what's the exact role of strncpy here ! and can someone please expalin this code for my cuz im beginner in network programming and thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `strncpy((char*)&sa, "", sizeof sa);`

   Here author is trying to set `0` to every byte of `sa` structure.

   As per [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/)

   > If the end of the source C string (which is signaled by a
   >   null-character) is found before num characters have been copied,
   >   destination is padded with zeros until a total of num characters have
   >   been written to it.

   If I were you I would do it this way.

   `memset(&sa, 0 , sizeof sa);`

---

2. `strncpy((char*)&sa.sin_addr, (char*) host->h_addr, sizeof sa.sin_addr);`

   Here Author is trying to copy `char *h_addr` which holds first host address to `s_addr`.

   If I were you I would do it this way.

   `sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host->h_addr);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it sets **sa** bits to zero.
It's probably equivalent to

```c
memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);
```

or, if your compiler allows it, you can use

```c
struct sockaddr_in sa = {.sin_family = AF_INET };
```

and get rid of

```c
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
```